# How to hide status bar in Android w/ React Native?

Tags: react-native

How to hide status bar in Android w/ React Native?

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbarios.html#content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [react-native-android-statusbar](https://github.com/NishanthShankar/react-native-android-statusbar)
.

```
var StatusBarAndroid = require('react-native-android-statusbar');
StatusBarAndroid.hideStatusBar()
```

Answer (score 7):

You no longer need to install a dependency to hide the status bar in `react-native`. The following should work for both Android and iOS.

To hide the `StatusBar` you can use the component straight from `react-native`. It is listed in the documentation [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar.html).

You can use it in two different ways. One as a component, and the other imperatively. For both you import it from `react-native`.

```
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';
```

#### Component

In side your render:

```
render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar hidden={true} /> // <- you could set this from a value in state
       ...
    </View>
  );
}
```

## Imperatively

This allows you to hide it via a function call.

```
componentDidMount () {
  // doesn't have to be in the componentDidMount it could be in some other function call.
  StatusBar.isHidden(true);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

<StatusBar backgroundColor={'transparent'} translucent={true} />

:D

[image]

Comment: can you add explanation instead of code only answer?